# At what point should I worry about high temperatures?

Tags: laptop, cpu, overheating, temperature, multi-core

I just got a new system76 galago pro.  It's nice.  It has 8 threads and lots of memory.  I do a lot of multicore computing in R, and a lot of my jobs are borderline between something that I'd do locally and something that I'd do on a large AWS instance.  I got this machine -- replacing a thinkpad x250 with a dead motherboard -- to save me the hassle of sending medium-sized jobs to the instance.

Immediately I booted it up and installed dropbox, and the fan gets going.  I install a desktop applet that monitors temperature.  I've never done so before.  Dropbox syncing plus a browser keeps the cpu between 55 and 65.  I've read somewhere that core i7 processors should stay below 65.

I got to wondering how this machine would handle larger jobs, so I wrote the following R script:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(detectCores())

f <- function(N = 1e4){
  m <- matrix(rnorm(N^2), nrow = N)
  d <- crossprod(m)
  return(NULL)
}

foreach(i = 1:8)%dopar%{
  while(TRUE){
    f()
  }
}
```

Basically the function `f` takes the cross-product of a 10K x 10k matrix, and discards the output.  I run this `while(TRUE)` on all 8 cores.  This is the result (look at the lower right for the temperature):
[image]

74 degrees!

My questions:

1. Is this something that I should worry about?
2. Is it something that will shorten the lifespan of the machine if I
   do it a lot?
3. Should the system76 folks not have offered a 8-thread processor in a
   laptop without better cooling?
4. Is there something I can do about this, besides turning the laptop
   upside down when plugged into my external monitor?  (Doing so
   decreases temp by ~5 degrees).

Comment: I'd assume that a call to System76 would answer several questions for you.  Have you installed anything to manage power, such as TLP?

Comment: No, I'm new to power management.  I've skimmed articles that mention TLP, but not read them in depth.  Mostly I want to know whether this is a big deal or not.

Comment: Not a big deal.

Comment: Just called system76 folks.  They said the same as @MichaelBay -- that 74 is NBD.  But glad to have a bit of confirmation

Comment: If you're concerned about overheating in general, google then install `powerclamp`.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I don't see any reference for a package for powerclamp - do you have some information about it?

Comment: @charlesgreen askubuntu.com/questions/391474/stop-cpu-from-overheating/875872#875872

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix This is my point - powerclamp is not a stand-alone package, but a lernel module which may have been blacklisted for some reason.  I use TLP, and find that both intel_rapl and intel_powerclamp are present in lsmod, thus apparently running.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Sorry the original message was posted from my phone which is why I said to "google" it first then install. I honestly couldn't remember. The second comment was also from my phone on browser and I couldn't read the wide page because it was outside of stack exchange mobile in order to gain link address. It wasn't until I got TLP installed myself that fan speeds and heat levels worked like a charm :)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Make sense!  I haven't tried stack exchange on the phone yet - fat fingers, you know...  With 17.10 I needed to install fancontrol, and I'm really less than thrilled with the overall result.

Comment: @generic_user +1 because Charles and I got to use your question thread to elaborate on thermal issues.

Comment: @CharlesGreen The worst one for me was i8kfancontrol or something like that which made video stutter every 10 seconds. I'm avoiding 17.10 like the plague. Too busy getting Windows 10 with WSL and new laptop with NVMe figured out~!